# Discovering an embedded device's IP address

Tags: networking, embedded, service-discovery

I am working on a small embedded device based upon an STM32F4xx MCU. It implements a TCP/IP server over a Wi-Fi connection. The question I have relates to exposing the IP address of the device so that it may be discovered by computers on the same network. UPnP and SSDP seem to be rather "heavy" solutions to this problem.

Are there other techniques/protocols that have a smaller footprint than UPnP and SSDP?

Thanks in advance for your input,
Sid

Comment: is it hardcoded or use dhcp to find an ip address?  should be easy to ask the dhcp server to see who just got added or removed when you connect or disconnect or power cycle.  If this is your product you are picking the mac addresses yes?  you have those on a sticker on the product?  a barcode?  arp makes it pretty easy then.  if the ip address is hardcoded (very bad idea) put that on a sticker/barcode...

Comment: if you know the hostname then you are done, elementary tools will get you the address...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make up any custom protocol, a simple UDP beacon periodically sent to the broadcast address (255.255.255.255 or your preferred interface's broadcast address) is simple and reliable.

Synopsis of comments:
For listing in mainstream platforms' (Windows, Linux, OS X) network views, the best option would likely be to implement the full stack required for Windows' Network Discovery.
If hostname lookup is enough, Netbios or mDNS could be enough.
The search term you are likely looking for is [zero-configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) and should give you all the available options

Comment: That is a solution I have used in the past, however it would need an application running on the computer to receive and display it. I could go that way but I would prefer not to have an additional program to write (on several platforms) and distribute, thanks.

Comment: What kind of platforms do you want to support? How do you want it to be detected? Is lookup by hostname enough or do you want it to be listed in e.g. Windows' Network Discovery?

Comment: I need to support Windows, Linux, and macOS. Ideally, the device should appear in the network view of the computer.

Comment: Lookup by hostname may also be acceptable

Comment: Getting it listed in the network view for all those platforms is likely going to take quite a large stack. I haven't attempted it, but I would guess Windows' Network Discovery would have some support on all platforms.

Comment: Easiest for lookup by hostname would likely be Netbios or mDNS

Comment: The search term you are likely looking for is [zero-configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) and should give you all the available options.

Comment: If you could edit your answer to include the last comment I am happy to mark it as the answer